# matching elements using OR with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, logical-operators

i m using regex in python to extract data from html. the regex that i ve written is like this:

```
result = re.findall(r'<td align="left"  csk="(\d\d\d\d)\d\d\d\d"><a href=.?*>(.*?)</a></td>\s+|<td align="lef(.*?)" >(.*?)</td>\s+', webpage)
```

assuming that this will the td which follows either of the format -

```
<td align="left"  csk="(\d\d\d\d)\d\d\d\d"><a href=.?*>(.*?)</a></td>\s+
```

OR

```
<td align="lef(.*?)" >(.*?)</td>
```

this is because the td can take different format in that particular cell (either have data with a link, or even just have no data at all).

I assume that the OR condition that i ve used is incorrect - believe that the OR is matching only the "just" preceding regex and the "just" following regex, and not between the two entire td tags.

my question is, how do i group it (for example with paranthesis), so that the OR is matched between the entire td tags.

Comment: Please, don't parse html with regex. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1248554)!

Comment: i understand the limitations of regex. I was wondering about how the OR can be applied in general and under such situations :)

Answer (score 3):

You are using a regular expression, but matching XML with such expressions gets too complicated, too fast.

Use a HTML parser instead, Python has several to choose from:

- [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is part of the standard library
- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a popular 3rd party library
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a fast and feature-rich C-based library.

ElementTree example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('filename.html')
for elem in tree.findall('tr'):
    print ElementTree.tostring(elem)
```

Comment: as long as there is no nesting it should theoretically work... that said regex is a poor tool choice for parsing xml/html

Answer (score 0):

In `<td align="left"  csk="(\d\d\d\d)\d\d\d\d"><a href=.?*>(.*?)</a></td>\s+` the `.?*` should be replaced with `.*?`.

And, to answer your question, you can use non-capturing grouping to do what you want as follows:

```
(?:first_regex)|(?:second_regex)
```

BTW. You can also replace `\d\d\d\d` with `\d{4}`, which I think is easier to read.